Jaspersoft + Java -> Generate PDF
Tengo un ReportePrincipal.jrxml que tiene 3 subreportes (promociones, grupo de explotacion y productos). Dentro de productos, tengo otros 3 subreportes (modalidades de pago, ofertas y promociones).
Tengo el siguiente código Java para generar en pdf el reporte principal incluyendo todos los subreportes.
@GetMapping(value = "/api/v1/jasper/generate-pdf-hojas-campana", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> generatePdfFromJson(@RequestParam(required = true) Integer ID_HOJA_CAMPANA)
            throws SQLException {
        try {
            // Compilar los informes desde archivos JRXML
            JasperReport mainReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(MAIN_REPORT_PATH);
            JasperReport subreportPromos = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(SUBREPORT_PROMOS_PATH);
            JasperReport subreportGrupos = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(SUBREPORT_GRUPOS_PATH);
            JasperReport subreportProductos = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(SUBREPORT_PRODUCTOS_PATH);
            JasperReport subreportProducto1 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(SUBREPORT_PRODUCTO1_PATH);
            JasperReport subreportProducto2 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(SUBREPORT_PRODUCTO2_PATH);
            JasperReport subreportProducto3 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(SUBREPORT_PRODUCTO3_PATH);

            // Crear mapas de parámetros para los subreportes
            Map<String, Object> subreportParams = new HashMap<>();
            subreportParams.put("SUBREPORT_PROMOS", subreportPromos);
            subreportParams.put("SUBREPORT_GRUPOS", subreportGrupos);
            subreportParams.put("SUBREPORT_PRODUCTOS", subreportProductos);

            Map<String, Object> subreportParamsProductos = new HashMap<>();
            subreportParamsProductos.put("SUBREPORT_PROMOCIONES", subreportProducto3);
            subreportParamsProductos.put("SUBREPORT_MODALIDADES_PAGO", subreportProducto1);
            subreportParamsProductos.put("SUBREPORT_OFERTAS", subreportProducto2);

            // Combinar los mapas de parámetros
            Map<String, Object> allSubreportParams = new HashMap<>();
            allSubreportParams.putAll(subreportParams);
            allSubreportParams.putAll(subreportParamsProductos);

            // Obtener el JSON necesario para los datos del informe
            String jsonString = jasperHojasCampanaService.getJSONCollection(ID_HOJA_CAMPANA, dataSource, false)
                    .toString();
            byte[] bytes = jsonString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            // Crear un objeto JsonDataSource a partir de los datos JSON
            ByteArrayInputStream jsonDataStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            JsonDataSource jsonDataSource = new JsonDataSource(jsonDataStream);

            // Llenar el reporte principal con los datos y los parámetros de los subreportes
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(mainReport, allSubreportParams, jsonDataSource);

            // Exportar el informe a un arreglo de bytes en formato PDF
            byte[] pdfBytes = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);

            // Configurar las cabeceras de la respuesta para indicar que se devolverá un
            // archivo PDF
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
            headers.setContentDispositionFormData("ReportePrincipal", "hojas_campana_report.pdf");

            // Devolver el archivo PDF como un arreglo de bytes en la respuesta
            return new ResponseEntity<>(pdfBytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (JRException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error generating PDF", e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    
    }

En mi ReportePrincipal.jrxml he añadido 3 parametros para pasarle los subreports:
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_PROMOS" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport" />
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_GRUPOS" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport" />
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_PRODUCTOS" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport" />
<detail>
        <band height="620" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="-15" y="20" width="545" height="190" uuid="d4cc0820-2f42-4a40-9e3c-037aa293942f"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("PROMOCIONES")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_PROMOS}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="-15" y="216" width="545" height="230" uuid="c323823b-e298-468e-87b2-c382b5411533"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("GRUPO_EXPLOTACION")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_GRUPOS}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="-11" y="530" width="545" height="81" uuid="54b7058e-8668-4c71-af01-6ddfb8d7537b"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("PRODUCTOS.PRODUCTO")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_PRODUCTOS}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>

y en el SubreportProductos.jrxml exactamente lo mismo
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_PROMOCIONES" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_MODALIDADES_PAGO" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_OFERTAS" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>
<subreport>
                <reportElement x="60" y="70" width="420" height="30" uuid="4620ed97-047d-4d68-9854-aa0653330f94"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("promociones")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_PROMOCIONES}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="60" y="230" width="420" height="31" uuid="236a19ab-0af9-4299-8844-4cb001d2a08c"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("modalidades_pago")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_MODALIDADES_PAGO}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="60" y="310" width="140" height="20" uuid="287854df-4c5f-4843-8f94-ecd22d245110"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("ofertas")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_OFERTAS}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>

Me saca todo, pero el problema está en que los datos de los 3 subreportes que hay dentro del SubreportProductos me los saca vacios. Alguien sabe cual puede ser el fallo? Gracias.
